# Domestic arrival for international departure

Tags: international-travel, airport-security, connecting-flights, domestic-travel, atl

I am flying from Asheville (AVL) to Atlanta (ATL) - domestic - so I can catch an international flight from ATL to Paris.  Will this mean I have to go through security check in both Asheville AND Atlanta?

Atlanta is the connecting flight

All of my flights are on the same ticket.

Asheville > Atlanta > Paris

My luggage will be checked in Asheville, so it should arrive at my final destination.

Both the flight to Atlanta (from Asheville) and the flight to Paris (from Atlanta) are Air France.

Comment: It's not generally necessary to re-clear security in the US, but you might have to if you need to change terminals.  I'm not familiar enough with Atlanta to comment on that specifically.

Comment: Air France does not operate flights from Asheville to Atlanta.  That will be a code share with a partner airline (e.g., Delta, Delta Connection).  In fact, the flight from Atlanta to Paris could also be a Delta flight; it looks like Delta and Air France have roughly the same number of flights between the two airports.  This doesn't change the answer to your question, but it might make it easier for you to find your gate.

Comment: Domestic arrivals into ATL don't need to re-clear security, but international arrivals do.

Comment: @phoog All the terminals in Atlanta are connected by an underground railway (and even a walkway, if you're not in a hurry and feel like an air-conditioned stroll, or are just going one stop on the train).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your way to Paris, you don't have to check in or go through security at Atlanta. Your bags will be checked through and it will be just like a domestic connection as far as you're concerned.

On your way home, you will need to go through passport control and customs in Atlanta. You'll go through passport control, pick up your checked bags and take them through customs. As soon as you get through customs, there's a counter where you can drop your bag for it to be taken to Asheville. You'll then need to go through security again (you might have taken guns and knives and liquids and more guns out of your checked bags) but it's a dedicated checkpoint just for connecting passengers and the lines are usually short. Then you're good to go for your flight back to Asheville.

Comment: But this is a round trip on one ticket.  Asheville to Paris and back to Asheville.  Do I really have to go to baggage claim when getting to Atlanta?  My connection would only be ~2 hours for me to get back to Asheville.

Comment: @dockeryZ Yes, you have to do exactly as I described. All passengers arriving in the USA from abroad must go through immigration and customs at their point of arrival, and you must go through customs with your checked baggage. Two hours should be enough time when travelling on a foreign passport and plenty of time with a US passport. I've entered the US through Atlanta a few times; I don't remember the exact layout but, as far as I remember, everywhere I've entered the USA, there has been almost zero walking from immigration to baggage reclaim to customs to baggage recheck to security.

Comment: @dockeryZ you cannot avoid going to baggage claim because when you arrive in Atlanta from abroad, you will have to go to passport control.  When you leave the passport control area, you will be in the baggage claim area.  From there, the only exit is through the customs checkpoint into the unsecured part of the airport. 
 The only way you can get to the gate for your next flight, or to anywhere else for that matter, is by passing through these areas.  I don't know what happens if you don't wait to pick up your bags and carry them through customs, but I expect it's inconvenient.

Comment: Well that sucks. I sure hope 2 hours is enough time.  Everytime I've been to baggage claim in ATL it takes forever.

Comment: @dockeryZ indeed.  I usually arrive in JFK, and usually get through passport control before the bags are delivered to the carousel, where I sometimes have to wait for a very long time indeed.  However, I live nearby so I don't have to worry about connecting flights.  Fortunately for you, you should at least be able to proceed to your gate in fairly short order once you get your bags, thanks to the dedicated bag drop and security checkpoint.  If you miss your flight, the airline will of course rebook you on the next one.

Comment: @phoog "dedicated bag drop"? Is this the same as going all of the way to the baggage claim carousel, or are you implying there is some kind of dedicated area on the way to customs for re-checking your luggage?

Comment: @dockeryZ yes, it's the same as going all the way to the carousel, because the dedicated bag drop is after the carousel.  It's also *after the customs checkpoint* (because the whole point of the exercise is for you to clear the customs checkpoint *with your checked luggage),* but it's immediately after the customs checkpoint, so you don't have to wait in line with all the people who are arriving at the airport to check in for their first flight.

Comment: @dockeryZ The baggage claim carousel is immediately after passport control, and the dedicated recheck area is immediately after customs.